# Redshift alarm - HealthStatus and MaintenanceMode composite

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-cloudwatch, alarm

I have an alarm set on the HealthStatus metric of Redshift cluster which is getting triggered whenever there is any Maintenance event happening on the cluster resulting in false alarm triggers.

In order to mitigate this I tried to setup a composite alarm with HealthStatus and MaintenanceMode metrics combined `ALARM(HealthStatus) AND NOT ALARM(MaintenanceMode)`

Upon the next occurrence of cluster maintenance event the composite alarm still got triggered. Upon investigation I found that the HealthStatus metric, after going into ALARM, goes back into OK state a minute late.

Please find below the data explaining this :
**Cluster Maintenance**
2003 (started) - 00:04:00
3519 (restart begin) - 00:26:00
3520 (restart done) - 00:26:00
2004 (complete) - 00:31:00

**MaintenanceMode**
ALARM - 00:05:23
OK - 00:31:23

**HealthStatus**
ALARM - 00:21:49
OK. - 00:32:49

**Composite Alarm**
ALARM - 00:31:23
OK. - 00:32:49

It can be seen that the composite alarm when into ALARM state only because of that extra time period [00:31:23 - 00:32:49] where the Maintenance was over but the HealthStatus alarm was in ALARM state for extra 1 minute 49 seconds.

Trying to understand why the HealthStatus alarm is not back to normal for extra minute after the maintenance event is over and how can this be mitigated to avoid HealthStatus alarm from getting triggered during maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

The Redshift monitoring system determines "health" by issuing a simple query to the cluster every minute.  This is done based on "wall clock".  So when a cluster becomes available again it can take up to a minute for the metric to show a return to "healthy" status.

To work around this you can try to base your alarm on multiple "unhealthy" statuses in a row.